# Bulk update with cron doesn't work - Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, cron, magento2

i have a problem with Bulk update in Magento 2.4.3.

if I make a bulk edit of some products I get the message:

```
Message is added to queque
```

but a second later this error appears:

```
Task "Update attributes for 2 selected products" : 1 item(s) failed to update"
```

if i see the details:
[image]

and I also have a problem when I launch from the command line the following instruction:

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

this is the error:

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /generated/metadata/global.php on line 236136
    PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /generated/metadata/global.php on line 236136
Ran jobs by schedule.
```

but i have set memory limit to  -1

How can I solve it?

Comment: I replaced the error images with the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by deleting the cron tasks from the database and then instead of launching the `php bin/magento cron:run` command, I launched the `php bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update --max-messages=20` command by setting a cron every hour, so it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with your memory limit setting on phpifno()

for the time being there is workaround to memory limit using the following command:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento cron:run
```

Comment: as master value I have -1 but as local value I have 756M. While the command doesn't work, it tells me that Could not open input file: bin/mangeto even though they are in the correct magento folder

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, its bin/magento; edited the answer;
magento 2 requirement is 2GB of memory, it should be the memory limit that hampering your command;

Comment: I tried the correct command, but it comes up with the same error

Answer (score 0):

This is caused 1 of 2 possible issues, and should be checked in this order:

**(1)** You absolutely do not have even memory assigned to Magento. It doesn't really matter if you -1 at the PHP level, if the OS level isn't assigning enough Memory, you're stuck. Check with your host.

**(2)** you have an error within your bulk update script, or some code elsewhere that is exhausting the memory allocation.

**BUT** as memory is exhausted at what is effectively 0.13Gb and, as `archvayu`
mentioned above, you need at least 2Gb, I'd look straight into **(1)** before doing anything else.